# TCP connection is being closed before I can get a user input

Tags: go, goroutine

I have setup a server to wait for a TCP connection and read an input from the user:

```
func main() {
  err := godotenv.Load()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+os.Getenv("PORT"))

  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  log.Println("HTTP Server Listening on port :", os.Getenv("PORT"))
  defer server.Close()

  for {
    conn, err := server.Accept()
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go handleConn(conn)
  }
}
```

The issue I am having is in my `handleConn` function. I want to kick off reading the input into a goroutine because there will be additional data processing. However, when I connect to my server (`nc localhost 9000`), my connection gets dropped immediately.

```
func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
  defer conn.Close()
  io.WriteString(conn, "Enter a transaction:")

  scanner := bufio.NewScanner(conn)

  go func() {
    for scanner.Scan() {
      log.Println("User entered: ")
      log.Println(scanner.Text())
    }

  }()
}
```

I see the message `Enter a transaction:`, but I am not able to input anything because my connection is immediately terminated and I am kicked back to my bash terminal. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I am following this tutorial - https://github.com/mycoralhealth/blockchain-tutorial/blob/master/networking/main.go.

I have tried moving `scanner.Scan()` outside the goroutine and this works, but the code example here has it within the goroutine and his example works. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're spawning a goroutine in your `handleConn` func, it doesn't need to wait for anything to return, so the deferred `conn.Close()` runs and closes the connection. You might need to run `scanner.Scan()` out of the goroutine so that it blocks waiting for input.

Comment: I was following this tutorial - https://github.com/mycoralhealth/blockchain-tutorial/blob/master/networking/main.go. He places scanner.Scan() within the goroutine as well and I tested his code and it works. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: Probably because https://github.com/mycoralhealth/blockchain-tutorial/blob/a41d723d52fd011ab4a0a1691c06ba46ab100a75/networking/main.go#L115 blocks on waiting to receive from that channel, which the goroutine is sending to after getting user input.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the explanation Carlos! Didn't realize that the variable they used was actually a channel.